# How to make bitnami/kafka accessible from external via clusterip

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, bitnami

On this document.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka

it mentioned following:

```
Note: the deployed ingress must contain the following block:

tcp:
  9094: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}/{{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-0-external:9094"
  9095: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}/{{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-1-external:9094"
  9096: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}/{{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-2-external:9094"
```

what does this means? what is this configuration? is this helm chart configuration or k8s configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by referring to this guide.

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/nginx_tcp_udp_ingress/

I was missing this step

```
kubectl patch deployment ingress-nginx-controller --patch "$(cat ingress-nginx-controller-patch.yaml)" -n ingress-nginx
```

ingress-nginx-controller-patch.yaml

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        ports:
         - containerPort: 6379
           hostPort: 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this reference points to the values.yaml of ingress controller Helm charts, there is a section where you can mention the TCP and UDP ports that you want to allow traffic to, Ingress by default does not support TCP or UDP services. For this reason this Ingress controller uses the flags --tcp-services-configmap and --udp-services-configmap to point to an existing config map where the key is the external port to use and the value indicates the service to expose using the format:

```
 <namespace/service name>:<service port>:[PROXY]:[PROXY]
```

Ingress controller helm chart: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

TCP reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md

```
#Ingress-nginx values.yaml sample below
# TCP service key:value pairs
tcp:
#  8080: "default/example-tcp-svc:9000"

# UDP service key:value pairs
udp: {}
#  53: "kube-system/kube-dns:53"
```

Comment: where should I put these "#Ingress-nginx values.yaml sample"? under  helm.yaml?

Comment: I figure it out, I should put these settings into tcp-services configmap? what's next? it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To connect to your Kafka server from outside the cluster, follow the instructions below:

    Kafka brokers domain: Use your provided hostname to reach Kafka brokers, 192.168.49.2

    Kafka brokers port: You will have a different port for each Kafka broker starting at 9094

Comment: I can't access kafka from 192.168.49.2:9094 still

Comment: These values are specific to helm install (helm charts like i mentioned), when you install the chart, you need to pass the values. helm install name chart-name -f values.yaml